# HttpPost return a empty body

Tags: java, http-post, httpclient

I have the code below, and my problem is that the response.status is 200 (is ok) and my response body is empty and it should return a json response. Is the problem the length maybe?:`

```
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/rest/login");
    httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    List<NameValuePair> formParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    NameValuePair pair = new BasicNameValuePair("token",token);
    formParams.add(pair);
    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formParams);
    post.setEntity(entity);


    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
    this.code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    InputStream body = response.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));`
```

Comment: the token is valid, with postman is ok.

Comment: Stick some breakpoints or Console outputs in your local REST service and see what inputs are coming in from your POST operation. And see what is being served back to the client by way of response. I'd also check your MimeType for the response. I'm guessing it should be "application/json".

Comment: My Post call return a token in Json format, but I don't know what is the problem. With Postman (Chrome tool) I can se the body with this json without problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. In my case it was also very strange, that when url contained IP instead of hostname, it worked (I get the nonempty response).

However, setting netscape cookie specs helped in my case.

```
httpClientBuilder.setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
            .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.NETSCAPE)
            .build());
```